Optimization Issues in Convex Function with scipy.optimize and cvxpy
I'm encountering challenges while simulating an algorithm. I'm working to optimize a convex function (theoretically convex since it originates from -2log(p(X; Y)), relating to a Maximum Likelihood Estimation problem), where the variable Y is an m*m symmetric positive definite matrix.
Using scipy.optimize, I can successfully optimize the function in one-dimensional and two-dimensional cases. However, in three dimensions, optimization only works with small data sets; larger sets fail. I switched to using cvxpy, but even for two-dimensional systems, it errors out with "You are trying to minimize a function that is concave."
Here's a generalized framework of the function in Python, omitting some of the calculation details:
def compute_Y(Y, ...):
    term1 = T * (np.log(np.linalg.det(Y))+1e-8)
    term = np.zeros((m, m))
    for t in range(T):
        term += term_data[t]  
    term2 = np.trace(np.linalg.inv(Y) @ term) # 'term' is theoretically a symmetric positive definite matrix
    return term1 + term2 

In cvxpy, it looks like:
def compute_Y(Y, ...):
    term1 = T * (cp.log_det(Y))
    term = np.zeros((m, m))
    for t in range(T):
        term += term_data[t]  # Assuming term_data is structured appropriately
    M = cp.Variable((m, m))
    constraints = [Y @ M == term]
    term2 = cp.trace(M)
    return term1 + term2, constraints

alternatively:
def compute_Y(Y, T, term_data):
    term1 = T * cp.log_det(Y)
    term = np.zeros((m, m))
    for t in range(T):
        term += term_data[t]  
    term_L = np.linalg.cholesky(term, lower=True)
    term2 = cp.matrix_frac(term_L, Y)
    return term1 + term2

How can I resolve the concavity error with cvxpy, improve the optimization performance with scipy.optimize in the higher-dimensional case, or are there other optimization methods?

You could speed up the scipy.optimize approach by supplying an explicit derivative. If you do not supply this derivative, it must be estimated by making N calls to your objective function, where N is the number of variables in your problem.

Is term_data a constant, or is it one of the variables you're optimizing?

term_data is computed from variables, but it is a constant within the function.

If it's constant, could you pre-compute it before optimizing? This would save you time when the objective function is evaluated.

You're right! I'll give it a try. But that doesn't solve my problem - the issue is not that the runtime is too long, but that I can't find the optimal value when dealing with 3D or large data volumes.

Oh, I see. I misunderstood what you meant by "How can I [...] improve the optimization performance with scipy.optimize in the higher-dimensional case"
